# how to delete tablerow using uiactionsheet?

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have a tableview of items and when i click one row, I use uiactionsheet with 3 button: edit, remove and cancel. When I click button edit, I will open a modal view, so how can I do this ? what is the code to delete tablerow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete a row from a `UITableView`, use the method named `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. You can find all the details on the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) page.

Also don't forget to remove the corresponding item from your model!

Comment: you could store the NSIndexPath of the selected row right before you show the UIActionSheet. Then upon the delegate-callback of the clicked button, use that NSIndexPath to perform the deletion: `[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

UIActionSheet has a delegate property.  Add the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol to your view controller and set yourself as the delegate to the action sheet before you display it.

The action sheet will call

```
– actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

on it's delegate when the user selects and action.
In your implementation of this, you can do what you want, such as delete the row as fguchelaar described.
This method doesn't directly know which row the action sheet was called for, so you can either subclass UIActionSheet so it can store the indexPath, store the indexPath in your viewController, or pass the information in some other way.